# Sprout Email Plugin and Multilanguage. How to translate SubjectLine?

Tags: localization, plugin-sproutemail

I use Sprout Email on a website to send transactional email (about 15 different types).

The website gets now translated to 3 languages (DE/FR/EN). It is all fine, but of course, also the transactional emails need to be in three languages.

As Sprout Email does not really support localization, it is still somehow possible by adding 3 "Email Body" fields to the email field layout:

- emailBodyDe
- emailBodyFr
- emailBodyEn

In the mail template, I can then chose which body to use. All good so far.

```
{% set locale = object.locale %}
{% set emailBody = email.htmlEmailBodyDe %}
{% set emailSubject = email.subjectLine %}
{% switch locale %}
    {% case "fr" %}
        {% set emailBody = email.htmlEmailBodyDe %}
        {# ... set subject!? ... #}
    {% case "en" %}
        {% set emailBody = email.htmlEmailBodyEn %}
        {# ... set subject!? ... #}
{% endswitch %}
```

But I can't translate the subject line. There is just one fixed field in Sprout Email for that.

Any suggestions how I can also make the subject field multi-language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we'll be adding native support for localization in Craft 3. This is a bit trickier in Craft 2 right now.

Two thoughts. You could set up 3 different emails (each managed in a different language) to be triggered off the same event. Not ideal, but an option.

Aside from that, Sprout Email does run the `subjectLine` field through `renderObjectTemplate` so you could use a field in whatever is triggering your event as a dynamic variable for the Subject Line.

Comment: Yes, I went with the second idea you provided. My current subject line looks like this: `{% switch object.orderLocale %}{% case 'de' %}Deine Buchungsbestätigung...{% case 'fr' %}...{% case 'en' %}...{% endswitch %}`, Not ideal, but it works so far :)